# Pygame tower defense game, issues with finding a target

Tags: python, pygame

I'm doing a little Tower Defense project in Python and I'm having some issues with targeting I can't figure out.

So I have a list of towers and a list of enemies that move around.

Every time the while loop for the main game logic iterates I have a function that checks if each of the spawned towers have a target. If they don't, I run a function that should find one.

```
for tw in tower_list:
    tw.render(window)
    if tw.target == None:
        print(tw)
        tw.target = find_target(tw)
        print(tw.target)
```

That's done in the `find_target` function. I'm sending the tower thats looking for a target.

```
def find_target(tw):
    for e in enemy_list:
        closest = 100000,100000
        print("Checking distance for enemy", e)
        dx = tw.x - e.x
        dy = tw.y - e.y
        if dy < 0:
            dy *= -1
        if dx < 0:
            dx *= -1
        if dx <= closest[0] and dy <= closest[1]:
            closest = dx, dy
            print("Closest one is ",e,"at distane",closest)
            return e
```

My simulation currently includes 3 different enemies and I spread them out so that every tower should have a different enemy as its target. But it always only checks and returns the same enemy.
[image]

It's probably something stupid I forgot, but I really can't think of it at the moment.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the carthesian distance formula to calculate distances between two points.

[image]

It will make it so you always have one value for distance and guarantee you have the lesser distance every time.
Right now if for instance one enemy is within distance 1 in the x axis from every tower and all the others are within distance 2 in the x axis they will never be selected even though they might be closer

EDIT:
Please use the formula above as your calculation is not a distance function
Also in your function you return e at the first time you find something smaller than closer.
Id make it so that closest is a tuple holding an enemy and the distance, and therefore your code should be

```
def find_target(tw):
    closest = (10000, None)
    for e in enemy_list:

            print("Checking distance for enemy", e)
            dx = tw.x - e.x
            dy = tw.y - e.y
            distance = math.hypot(dx, dy)
            if distance < closest[0]
                closest[0] = distance
                closest[1] = e

    print("Closest one is ",closest[1],"at distane",closest[0])
    return closest
```

Comment: That was probably it... Thanks a lot

Comment: Looks like thats not it after i actually figured out the reason but I can't understand why. It only runs for e in enemy_list , once aka it checks only for the 1 element not all 3

Comment: Still i'd change the distance function because your calculation is not a distance function at all.
The reason is because your return is inside the loop and not at the end of the loop.
You cannot return first time you find an element

Comment: @Havok224 this is most likely the right solution. If there are any other problems, you need to post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). BTW, you can use `math.hypot` here: `distance = math.hypot(dx, dy)`.

Comment: @skrx Updating with your function, Good call

Comment: Yeah, my calculation method was definitely horrible, but I didn't even spot the indentation problem. Again thanks a lot.

Comment: @skrx thanks that cut down the massive blob of code i just made nicely

Comment: @Havok224 you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark below the arrows if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a range for the tower and find if enemies in the range:

```
self.in_range = False
enemies_closest = []
enemies = [] #whatever enemies you have
for enemy in enemies:
    x, y = enemy.x, enemy.y
    dis = math.sqrt((self.x - x)**2 + (self.y - y)**2)
    if dis < self.range:
        self.in_range = True
        enemies_closest.append(enemy)
enemies_closest.sort(key=lambda x: x.path_pos)
if len(enemies_closest) > 0:
    target = enemies_closest[0]
```

but your method really should be fine...